# Proper Formatting of SQL Statements for SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a few create statements that should be run when a database is first created in my Android application.  They are formatted as such:

```
<string-array
        name="uaDBcreates">
        <item>
            CREATE TABLE pos_locations (
                _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                location_name TEXT,
                service_url TEXT,
                latitude REAL DEFAULT 0,
                longitude REAL DEFAULT 0
            );
        </item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array
        name="uaDBInserts">
        <item>
            INSERT INTO urbanAgendaDB.pos_locations (
                    _id,
                    location_name,
                    service_url
                    latitude,
                    longitude )
                VALUES (
                    000001,
                    OfficeTest,
                    http://myservice.com/DoStuff,
                    45.530315,
                    -73.569939);
        </item>
    </string-array>
```

Generally, is this the proper formatting for SQL statements that could be run in SQLite on Android (are thise likely to work)?  More specifically, parts of the Android docs state SQL statements should not terminated with a semi-colon, while parts make no mention of semi-colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `INSERT` statements with a direct SQL syntax, only by means of the `SQLDatabase` API; but from my experience I would say that your `CREATE` statement will work as written.

As far as the API docs are concerned, it's quite simple: use those statements with whatever method allows semicolons; strip semicolons if you need to use those same statements with methods that do not allow them at their end. (You may also work it the other way around: avoid semicolons in your statements, then add proper ending punctuation only when you use those statements with API methods requiring semicolons.)

However, I'm a bit baffled by the fact you are including your SQL statements in XML (not to mention that they are the only item in a `string-array`). Typically, I'm used to see them in Java code, under the form of `String` concatenations.

Comment: The use of the string array is because there will probably be multiple statements to run.  The reason I have them in an XML file is to keep everything related to the DB in on place.  If you could point me to resource that shows the best place to keep SQL statements, since all tutorials and resources I have read have been pretty simplistic; only showing whats necessary to use SQLite on Android.

Comment: @MikeD I don't have what you may call an authoritative source, but I've seen database interaction typically kept in a single class: a Content Provider, or a simple wrapper if the developer wants their own application to directly access the database. That class is the place where everything related to the database is stored. Statements such as your `CREATE`, for example, are stored in `static final String` fields, and used whenever appropiate.